# Create ConfigMap through kubectl task

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, configmap

As part of the build pipeline I wanted to create a ConfigMap with the content of a file which is part of the Git repository from which the pipeline runs.

According to the Kubectl task für Azure Pipelines, this should be possible. But I have no idea how to apply it. It doesn't matter how my YAML is look like for this task, the result is always 'success'. Even I enter `foo` / `bar` as input parameters.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/kubernetes?view=azure-devops

I asked Microsoft whether there could be a lack in the documentation or in the implementation itself. The only answer I get was ask here. They really move the responsibility for support to the community.

This is my definition:

```
- task: Kubernetes@1
  displayName: 'Create ConfigMap for /data'
  inputs:
    kubernetesServiceEndpoint: 'cluster-test'
    namespace: 'app-test'
    forceUpdateConfigMap: true
    configMapName: data
    configMapArguments: --from-file $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/data/ExcelTemplate.xlsx
```

With this I expect, according to the documentation, that with every run the ConfigMap will be deleted and recrated with the content of the given Excel file (and ExcelTemaplte.xlsx as the key).
Manuelly I can do this with:
`kubectl create configmap data --from-file ExcelTemplate.xlsx`

The linked documentation mention the usage like this (I d:

```
    - task: Kubernetes@1
      displayName: configMap with literal values
      inputs:
        azureSubscriptionEndpoint: $(azureSubscriptionEndpoint)
        azureResourceGroup: $(azureResourceGroup)
        kubernetesCluster: $(kubernetesCluster)
        command: apply
        arguments: -f mhc-aks.yaml
        secretType: generic
        secretArguments: --from-literal=contoso=$(contosovalue)
        secretName: mysecretkey4
        configMapName: myconfig
        forceUpdateConfigMap: true
        configMapArguments: --from-literal=myname=contoso
```

- The first part is clear, the example uses a Azure cluster, but there can be used any kind of.
- Why do they use `apply` with a `.yaml` file? What should be inside?
- Why do they deal with secrets, just a combined example? It's not mentioned
- `configMapArguments` is mentioned in the docs (a guess newly added, was not before)

But I can give for every of the ConfigMap parameters a random value and the task is even then successful. Or in return, I can configure correct values and the result is successful without doing anything.

```
- task: Kubernetes@1
  displayName: 'Create ConfigMap for /data'
  inputs:
    kubernetesServiceEndpoint: 'cluster-test'
    namespace: foobar # does not exist
    forceUpdateConfigMap: true
    configMapName: data
    configMapArguments: 'today is sunny'
```

Does someone already use this task for creating a ConfigMap? Or was successful in trying out this task?

For know I have to ran this task twice once with delete and once with a dedicated manifest for ConfigMap creation with the `apply` command. Or as a second solution just firing the `kubectl` commands for deletion/creation in bash script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems, that something has been fixed since last Friday. Now the following definition is working as expected:

```
- task: Kubernetes@1
  displayName: 'Create ConfigMap for /data'
  inputs:
    kubernetesServiceEndpoint: 'cluster-test'
    namespace: 'app-test'
    forceUpdateConfigMap: true
    configMapName: data
    configMapArguments: --from-file $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/data/ExcelTemplate.xlsx
```

Comment: Hi !Thanks for sharing the solution here, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Just a reminder of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) :)

Comment: If I don't specify the command "create", the pipeline appears to do nothing. I know its been a while since the post, but do you have any idea how to use the config map keys in the docs?